# How can I get FreeBSD `patch` to tolerate null bytes?

Tags: freebsd, posix, patch, null

The patch of the final line fails on FreeBSD 10.2, but works on GNU:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo a > f1
printf '\0' >> f1
echo c >> f1
cp f1 f2
echo d >> f2
diff -au f1 f2 > diff
patch < diff
```

Is FreeBSD incapable of this? The man page does not mention null bytes.

Comment: It is not an uncommon limitation, since null-bytes are not used in *text* files.  There is of course a FreeBSD port for GNU patch.

Answer (score 3):

`patch` is designed for text files. Take a look at [`xxd`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xxd), which can patch binary files. It should be available for FreeBSD as well.

Comment: how do I generate something similar to unified diff's for xxd? I want to handle multiple files...

Comment: That sounds like a new question. ;)

Answer (score 2):

It is not an uncommon limitation, since null-bytes are not used in text files. There is of course a FreeBSD port for GNU patch.

For context, just looking at the manual pages for FreeBSD:

- [this is GNU diff](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=diff&sektion=1&apropos=0&manpath=FreeBSD%2010.2-RELEASE), agreeing with the [source repository](https://svnweb.freebsd.org/base/head/gnu/usr.bin/diff/), and is actually a little old ([8 years](https://svnweb.freebsd.org/base/head/contrib/diff/)).
- [this is not GNU patch](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?patch%281%29), again agreeing with the [source repository](https://svnweb.freebsd.org/base/head/usr.bin/patch/).

Both GNU patch and FreeBSD patch originated with Larry Wall's patch program, but the former has had more extensive changes.  In particular, GNU patch was extended to handle the embedded nulls which might be output by GNU diff.  Still, even *that* was done quite a while ago ([around 1992](https://svnweb.freebsd.org/base/head/contrib/diff/ChangeLog?revision=170755&view=markup#l2947) according to the [changelog](https://svnweb.freebsd.org/base/head/contrib/diff/ChangeLog?revision=170755&view=markup#l3069)).

For whatever reason, the FreeBSD developers did not incorporate this change.  If you need the feature on FreeBSD, you can use the port (or precompiled package) of GNU patch.  See [FreshPorts](https://www.freshports.org/devel/patch/) for a summary.